# Change code to use block RAMs

Tags: verilog

I want to implement in Verilog the following Matlab code:

```
symBuf = [symBuf(numFFT/2+1:end); zeros(numFFT/2,1)];
symBuf(KF+(1:KF)) = symBuf(KF+(1:KF)) + txSymb;
```

It is a simple overlap and add operation.

Here is my implementation:

```
module overlap
#(K = 3,
FFT = 128    
)
(
input signed [15:0] symbInReal      ,
input signed [15:0] symbInImag      ,
input clock                         ,
input reset                         ,
input readyIn                       ,
input validIn                       ,
input lastIn                        ,
output signed [15:0] outReal        ,
output signed [15:0] outImag        ,
output reg lastOut                  ,
output wire readyOut                ,
output reg validOut
);

reg signed [15:0] previousSymbolReal [2*FFT*K-1:0]      ;
reg signed [15:0] previousSymbolImag [2*FFT*K-1:0]      ;
reg signed [15:0] txSymbolBuffReal [K*FFT-1:0]          ;
reg signed [15:0] txSymbolBuffImag [K*FFT-1:0]          ;
reg [15:0] counter                                      ;
reg [1:0] state                                         ;
reg [3:0] nextstate                                     ;
reg [15:0] clockcount                                   ;
reg signed [15:0] outputValueReal                       ;
reg signed [15:0] outputValueImag                       ;
reg [15:0] buffcount                                    ;
reg [7:0] symboutcount                                  ;
reg [7:0] symbincount                                   ;
reg last                                                ;
reg lastvalidout                                        ;

wire lastout                                            ;

  integer i;
  initial begin 
    for (i=0; i<2*FFT*K ; i = i + 1) begin
            previousSymbolReal[i] = 0;
            previousSymbolImag[i] = 0;
    end
end  

always@(posedge clock) begin
    if(~reset) begin
        counter <= 0;
    end else begin
        counter <= counter +1;
        if(nextstate != state)
            counter <= 0;
    end
end

always@(*) begin
    if(~reset) begin
        nextstate = 0;
    end else begin 
        nextstate = state;
        if(readyIn) begin
            case(state)
                4'd0: begin
                        if(validIn || last) begin
                            nextstate = 1;
                        end 
                      end
                4'd1: begin 
                          if (counter == (FFT*K-2)) begin
                            nextstate = 2;
                          end
                  end
                4'd2: begin
                            nextstate = 0;          
                      end
            endcase
        end
    end
end

always@(posedge clock) begin
    if(~reset) begin
        state <= 0;
    end else begin
        if(readyIn)
            state <= nextstate;
    end
end

always@(posedge clock) begin
    if(~reset) begin
        clockcount <= 0;
        symboutcount <= 0;
        lastOut <= 0;
    end else begin
        if(readyIn) begin
            clockcount <= clockcount +1 ;    
            case(state)
                4'd0: begin
                        validOut <= 0;
                        clockcount <= 0;
                        lastOut <= 0;
                      end
                4'd1: begin
                        if(~lastvalidout) 
                            validOut <= 1;
                        outputValueReal <= previousSymbolReal[clockcount+ FFT/2];           
                        outputValueImag <= previousSymbolImag[clockcount+ FFT/2];           
                      end
                4'd2: begin
                        outputValueReal <= previousSymbolReal[clockcount + FFT/2];
                        outputValueImag <= previousSymbolImag[clockcount + FFT/2];
                        clockcount <= 0;
                        if(~lastvalidout)
                            validOut <= 1;
                        if(symboutcount == symbincount + 1 && last)
                            lastOut <= 1;
                        symboutcount <= symboutcount +1 ;
                      end
             endcase   
         end
     end
 end

assign readyOut = readyIn;

 genvar M; 
 generate
    for(M=0;M<K*FFT;M=M+1) begin
        always@(posedge clock) begin
            if(state==2) begin
                previousSymbolReal[M] <= previousSymbolReal[M+FFT/2];
                previousSymbolImag[M] <= previousSymbolImag[M+FFT/2];
            end
        end
    end
    for(M=K*FFT;M<2*K*FFT-FFT/2;M=M+1) begin
        always@(posedge clock) begin
            if(state==2) begin
                previousSymbolReal[M] <= previousSymbolReal[M+FFT/2]+txSymbolBuffReal[M-K*FFT];
                previousSymbolImag[M] <= previousSymbolImag[M+FFT/2]+txSymbolBuffImag[M-K*FFT];
            end
        end
    end
    for(M=2*K*FFT-FFT/2;M<2*K*FFT;M=M+1) begin
        always@(posedge clock) begin
            if(state==2) begin
                previousSymbolReal[M] <= txSymbolBuffReal[M-K*FFT];
                previousSymbolImag[M] <= txSymbolBuffImag[M-K*FFT];
            end
        end
    end
 endgenerate

 always@(posedge clock) begin
    if(~reset) begin
        buffcount <= 0;
        symbincount <= 0;
        last <= 0;
    end else begin
        if(validIn) begin 
            txSymbolBuffReal[buffcount] <= symbInReal;
            txSymbolBuffImag[buffcount] <= symbInImag;
            buffcount <= buffcount +1;
            if(buffcount == K*FFT-1) begin
                symbincount <= symbincount + 1;
                buffcount <= 0;
            end
            if(lastIn) 
                last <= 1;
        end
    end
 end 

 always@(posedge clock) begin
    if(~reset) 
        lastvalidout <= 0;
    else begin
        if(last && lastOut)
            lastvalidout <= 1;
    end
 end


 assign outReal = outputValueReal;
 assign outImag = outputValueImag;

endmodule
```

The problem here is that I have 4 huge arrays which take up to 4 times what is available in my FPGA.
Hence, I want to be able to use block RAMs. However, I don't think it's possible due to the number of read and write operations performed.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't think it's possible due to the number of read and write operations performed.

Correct. At least, not without major changes to your design.

A typical block RAM element can only read or write one (or *sometimes* two) values per clock cycle, but your `generate` loops are trying to update every element in the RAM at once!

To make this operation use a block RAM, you will need to implement a state machine to update one element per clock cycle, and to sequence operations such that other states wait until the updates have completed.

If you want to accelerate this, you may be able to split the array into multiple block RAMs so that multiple values can be updated in parallel. (You will need to carefully consider which elements need to be read/written to avoid conflicts.)

Comment: Thanks.

And using a block RAM can I do something along the lines of:

Prev[count] <= Prev[count] + 5;

In a single clock cycle ?

Comment: Sometimes -- it depends on the FPGA. Read the documentation to find out; some designs may only let you perform one operation (read OR write) per cycle.